# Email configuration from a form in the site

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-settings

Right now I have the email configuration in my setting.py but the configuration is static:

```
setting.py

#Mail configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

I have one user with the profile `global_admin` so what I need is when the `global_admin` are login in the site he could change the `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, `EMAIL_HOST`, `EMAIL_PORT` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` using one form.

Is posible use a form in the front end to change the data in the `setting.py` file using a view? that's the way I imagine that this could be solve but I don't know if is posible or I have to create a model for that configuration and use a custom `EmailBackend`?

Answer (score 1):

Create one new table called 'property_variables' (any name).

fields

1. property_name
2. property_value

Instead of specifying configurations in settings.py file, save these details in 'property_variables' table.

Example:

property_name - EMAIL_BACKEND

property_value - 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

For avoiding multiple DB hit, you can cache these details in redis or somewhere else.

When you want to sent email, instead of reading config details from settings.py file, read it from cache.

If you want to change the configuration, open admin panel and change values. You can invalidate the cache after the DB update.

**__init__.py**

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

CONFIGS = dict()


def read_config_variables():
    configs = MyModel.objects.all()
    for config in configs:
        CONFIGS[config.propertyName] = config.propertyValue

read_config_variables()
```

**settings.py**

```
import CONFIGS
EMAIL_BACKEND = CONFIGS.get('EMAIL_BACKEND', 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')
EMAIL_HOST = CONFIGS.get('EMAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com')
EMAIL_PORT = CONFIGS.get('EMAIL_PORT', 587)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = CONFIGS.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER', '*****@gmail.com')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = CONFIGS.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', '*******')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = CONFIGS.get('EMAIL_USE_TLS', True)
```

Comment: But if I try to get the data from the DB in my `settings` file gives me an error
`The SECRET_KEY setting must  not be empty` that happen when I use `from myapp.models import mymodel`

Comment: you are moving only email configuration right? why are you touching 'SECRET_KEY '? Secret key is mandatory.

Comment: Yes, only the email configuration, I actually don't touch the `SECRET_KEY` and is not empty.

Comment: let's say the user change the `EMAIL_HOST` still have to change manually in the `setting.py` file? that's what I get from the edited code

Comment: No. CONFIGS.get('EMAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com') means, if the value is not existing in 'CONFIGS' then by default it will take 'smtp.gmail.com'

Comment: Gives me an error when I try to import CONFIGS `ImportError: No module named CONFIGS`